# How to loop through javascript variables inside a html block?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to pass a html block to a email service `Nodemailer` JS function (I'm using Node.JS). I have an `items` array that needs to be sent in the email:

```
items = [ 
   { name: 'prod1', description: 'desc1', quantity: 666, price: 666.66 },
   { name: 'prod2', description: 'desc2', quantity: 555, price: 555.55 }
];
```

Here is the JS funcition. I'm using a `<table>` tag to put the elements of `items` array. I can put this html inside a JS variable before sending it to the function, but I'm not sure how to insert the items. How to make it work?

```
await email.sendEmail(user.email, 'Order confirmation',
      `<div style='text-align:center'>
      <p> Order Details </p> <hr>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td> ${items} </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table></div>`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the string containing the HTML in a loop before the call:

```
var rows = items.map(({name, description, quantity, price}) =>
    `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${description}</td><td>${quantity}</td><td>$${price}</td></tr>`).join('');
await email.sendEmail(user.email, 'Order confirmation',
      `<div style='text-align:center'>
      <p> Order Details </p> <hr>
      <table>
          <tbody>
              ${rows}
          </tbody>
      </table></div>`);
```

Comment: What if I put a `currency` inside `items` like "USD" or "BRL": `var rows = items.map(({name, description, quantity, currency, price}) =>`... is there a way to transform the number `price` into a string, and then format accordingly? Like "$ 6.00" for "USD" and "R$ 6,00" for "BRL". I'm used to format values using Angular Currency Pipe for it.

Comment: You could have a map like `const currency_map = { USD: "$", BRL: "R$"}`. Then you can use `${currency_map[currency]} ${price}`

Comment: You can also call the Angular Currency Pipe function to do it. I don't know what that is, but you can put any code you want inside `${...}`

Comment: but how to format the `price`? BRL format uses comma " , " instead of point " . "... Is there a way to avoid something like this: `<td> ${currency === 
 'BRL' ? price.toString().replace('.',',') : price } </td>`

Comment: I suggest you write a currency formatting function, then `${currencyFormat(currency)}`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through items and build your html table

```
var itemHtml = `<div style='text-align:center'>
      <p> Order Details </p> <hr>
      <table>
          <tbody>`;
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
  var item = items[i];
  itemHtml += `<tr>
     <td>${item.name}</td>
     <td>${item.description}</td>
     <td>${iten.quantity}</td>
     <td>${item.price}</td>
  </tr>`; 
}
itemHtml += `</tbody></table></div>`;
```

then use the variable in your email.

```
await email.sendEmail(user.email, 'Order confirmation', itemHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this.

```
const listItems = items.map((item) =>
    <td>{item.name}</td>
    <td>{item.desc}</td>
    <td>{item.price}</td>
    );
  return (
    <tr>{listItems}</tr>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested maps to loop through your items, and the properties of each item like so:

```js
items = [ 
   { name: 'prod1', description: 'desc1', quantity: 666, price: 666.66 },
   { name: 'prod2', description: 'desc2', quantity: 555, price: 555.55 }
];

var keys = Object.keys(items[0])

await email.sendEmail(user.email, 'Order confirmation',
      `<div style='text-align:center'>
      <p> Order Details </p> <hr>
      <table>
          <tbody>
            ${items.map(item => {
              return `<tr>${keys.map(key => {
                return `<td>${item[key]}</td>`
              }).join("")}</tr>`
            }).join("")} 
          </tbody>
      </table></div>`);
```